# Bash multiple string comparison with OR and NOT

Tags: bash, logical-operators

Pulling disk status from a disk array, I get "ready" and "online" as status for OK. Trying to trap this with an IF statement in bash, that will act if the value is *something else* than "ready" and "online".

The code snippet below works for trapping "OK" but I'd like to reverse it, so it traps if $diskstatus is NOT ready or online.

```
#!/bin/bash
diskstatus="online"
if [[ $diskstatus = online ]] || [[ $diskstatus = ready ]]; then echo "OK: $diskstatus"; fi
```

Have now tried nearly everything with brackets, quotes and whatnot but not getting any of it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, consider also the `case` statement.

```
case $diskstatus in
    online | ready) ;;
    *) echo "Not ok: $diskstatus";;
esac
```

The syntax may look arcane at first but you quickly get used to it.  I actually tend to prefer it over `if` for many things involving simple string pattern matching.  As a bonus, it's compatible with traditional `sh`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that. I use case a lot in command input parameter parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `regex` operator in `bash` with `[[` operator as below,

```
[[ ! $diskstatus =~ ^(ready|online)$ ]] && echo "Not OK: $diskstatus"
```

Also, observe that double-quotes are not needed either for the `regex` or for the variable part,  because neither *word-splitting* nor *pathname expansion(globbing)* will be performed in this context

Another `POSIX` way to do this, to add to [tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340004/5291015) would be as

```
if [ "$diskstatus" != "ready" ] && [ "$diskstatus" != "online" ]; then  echo "Not OK: $diskstatus"; fi
```

Comment: I had this solution in my mind, but I was squeezing my head how to make it  work. Nice job.

Comment: Thanks for the regex variety, for the sake of readability it is very elegant. I'll pick this one :)

Answer (score 0):

simply reversing equality and logical operator seems to work for me

```
$ diskstatus=onlin
$ if [[ $diskstatus != online ]] && [[ $diskstatus != ready ]]; then echo "NOK: $diskstatus"; fi
NOK: onlin
```

Comment: There is no reason to `export` the variable here.

Comment: @tripleee you're right, I removed the useless but harmless export

Answer (score 0):

Since *both* need to be false, you have to use an `and` statement.

```
if [[ $diskstatus != online ]] && [[ $diskstatus != ready ]]; then echo "OK: $diskstatus"; fi
```

Otherwise, since at least one of the conditions will always be true, your if statement's body will always run.